# Is there any difference between Meprobamate and Equanil?

Tags: drugs, pharmacology

My textbook mentions Meprobamate and Equanil separately, under Anxiolytic drugs and even provides two (not-so) *different* structures to back their claim.

[image]

However, Wikipedia would beg to differ:

> **Meprobamate** — marketed as Miltown by Wallace Laboratories and **Equanil** by Wyeth...

Which would naturally imply, that Meprobamate and Equanil are...the *same* thing. ಠ_ಠ

A quick search with Google Images got me this:

[image]

Now this particular textbook I use has, over the years, gained notoriety among several generations of us students as the *Mater Omnium Errorum*. So in all likelihood, my textbook's the one that's wrong here.

But since I'm not a Pharmacologist, I'd appreciate it if someone could verify if Meprobamate and Equanil are the *exact*, same, chemical.

I tried Google, but *that* endeavor wasn't particularly helpful.

Comment: The meprobamate structure appears to be the correct one and the pharmacopeias agree that the active ingredient in Equanil is meprobamate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pharmaceuticals with meprobamate as the active compound are marketed by different companies under different names.

Meprobamate is the International Nonproprietary Name (INN) for the drug.

Whether two pharmeceuticals with the same active components acutally have the same kinetics does depend on additional factors, such as the type of the filler.